# How to do autofill of data in shiny app using excel file

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I am trying to read a data set using the browse option to upload data from pc. After that, I want to display file content to be automatically filled by using first column entry.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)




ui<-(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Auto Fill"),
  sidebarPanel(
autoFillDF<-  fileInput('file1', 'Choose xlsx file',
          accept = c(".xlsx")),
  # actionButton("go", "update"),
 selectizeInput("p1", choices = autoFillDF$WorklistNo, selected = NULL, label = 'WorklistNo'),
 selectizeInput("p2", choices = NULL, label = 'Status'),
 selectizeInput("p3", choices = NULL, label = 'Plant'),

 ),
  mainPanel(
    DT::dataTableOutput('table')
  )
)
)

server<-(function(input, output, session) {

  updateApp <- reactive({
    data <- autoFillDF
    data <- data[data$WorklistNo %in% input$p1,]
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'p2', choices = data$Status, selected = data$Status, server = TRUE)
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'p3', choices = data$Plant, selected = data$Plant, server = TRUE)

    data
  })

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(
    DT::datatable(updateApp()) 
  )

})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This is my data set look like. I have to read all the column data. I want to put WorklistNo and rest should be autofill.

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: @ElvinMitchellToro

Comment: @Damian can you help

Comment: i couldn't run your existing code, it shows a bunch of errors. can you recheck please.

Comment: @amrrs I have edited code.. please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to understand your code and requirement and as per my understanding i have tried to build a simple solution to complete it...Please take a look on that..

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      fileInput("file_upload","Uplaod Data",buttonLabel = "Browse..",placeholder = "No file Selected")
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(3,
             uiOutput("p1_ui")
             ),
      column(3,
             uiOutput("p2_ui")
             ),
      column(3,
             uiOutput("p3_ui")
             )
        ),
    fluidRow(
      column(6,
             h3("Uploaded DATA"),
             DTOutput("uploaded_data_table")
             ),
      column(6,
             h3("Selected DATA"),
             DTOutput("selected_data_table")
             )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  values <- reactiveValues(
    upload_state = NULL
  )
  data_upload_fun<-eventReactive(input$file_upload,{
    req(input$file_upload)
    if(values$upload_state=='reset'||is.null(values$upload_state))
    {
      df<<-read.csv(input$file_upload$datapath,
                   header = TRUE)
      values$upload_state <- 'uploaded'
      df
    }  
  })
    output$uploaded_data_table <- renderDT({
    DT::datatable(data_upload_fun())
  })
  output$p1_ui<-renderUI({
    if(is.null(values$upload_state)|| values$upload_state=='reset')
    {
      selectInput("p1", choices = NULL, label = 'WLID')
    }
    else
    {
      data_upload_fun()
      selectInput("p1", choices = df$WLID, label = 'WLID')
    }
  })

  output$p2_ui<-renderUI({
    if(is.null(values$upload_state)|| values$upload_state=='reset')
    {
      selectInput("p2", choices = NULL, label = 'PLANT')
    }
    else
    {
      data_upload_fun()
      plant<-df[df$WLID==input$p1,2]
      selectInput("p2", choices = as.list(plant), label = 'PLANT')
    }
  })
  output$p3_ui<-renderUI({
    if(is.null(values$upload_state)|| values$upload_state=='reset')
    {
      selectInput("p3", choices = NULL, label = 'STATUS')
    }
    else
    {
      data_upload_fun()
      status<-df[df$WLID==input$p1 & df$PLANT==input$p2,3]
      selectInput("p3", choices = as.list(status), label = 'STATUS')
    }
  })

  output$selected_data_table<-renderDT({
    if(is.null(values$upload_state)|| values$upload_state=='reset')
    {
      returnValue()
    }
    else
    {
      data_upload_fun()
      data_to_show<-df[df$WLID==input$p1 & df$PLANT==input$p2 & df$STATUS== input$p3, ]
      DT::datatable(data_to_show)
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

UI LOOKS LIKE: [image]

DATA Looks like [image]

Please let me know if that works and anything to change...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried to integrate your code with my code, it still has an error to autofill the values. In the data set, I want to put a value of WorklistNo and then autofill the rest fields, so we can ignore WLID.So we have to read our file from the 2nd column. And my file requirement is in excel only, no csv for a client:) So we have to read our file from 2nd column

Comment: @NIrbhayMathur you can modify the code.also you can use xlsx package for read.xlsx function

Comment: Still, there is some problem in the code. Please have a look i posed it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56927812/after-browse-data-it-not-displayed-in-shiny-dashboard