# After browse data it not displayed in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I want to upload a file using "Browse option" after that, I want to do autofill of table using "WorklistNo"(means: choosing one input should fill rest field automatically) values and rest column should be auto fill. But I am getting some errors. 
Based on WorklistNo my other data should be populated in different input boxes in the shiny dashboard.

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      fileInput("file_upload","Uplaod Data",buttonLabel = "Browse..",placeholder = "No file Selected")
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(3,
             uiOutput("p1_ui")
      ),
      column(3,
             uiOutput("p2_ui")
      ),
      column(3,
             uiOutput("p3_ui")
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(6,
             h3("Uploaded DATA"),
             DTOutput("uploaded_data_table")
      ),
      column(6,
             h3("Selected DATA"),
             DTOutput("selected_data_table")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  values <- reactiveValues(
    upload_state = NULL
  )
  data_upload_fun<-eventReactive(input$file_upload,{
    req(input$file_upload)
    if(values$upload_state=='reset'||is.null(values$upload_state))
    {
      data_in<-read_xlsx(input$file_upload$datapath
                    )
      values$upload_state <- 'uploaded'
      data_in
    }  
  })
  output$uploaded_data_table <- renderDT({
    DT::datatable(data_upload_fun())
  })
  output$p1_ui<-renderUI({
    if(is.null(values$upload_state)|| values$upload_state=='reset')
    {
      selectInput("p1", choices = NULL, label = 'WorklistNo')
   } 
    else
    {
      data_upload_fun()
      selectInput("p1", choices = uploade_data$WorklistNo, label = 'WorklistNo')
    }
  })

  output$p2_ui<-renderUI({
    if(is.null(values$upload_state)|| values$upload_state=='reset')
    {
      selectInput("p2", choices = NULL, label = 'Status')
    }
    else
    {
      data_upload_fun()
      status<-data_in[data_in$WorklistNo==input$p1,2]
      selectInput("p2", choices = as.list(status), label = 'Status')
    }
  })
  output$p3_ui<-renderUI({
    if(is.null(values$upload_state)|| values$upload_state=='reset')
    {
      selectInput("p3", choices = NULL, label = 'Plant')
    }
    else
    {
      data_upload_fun()
      plant<-data_in[data_in$WorklistNo==input$p1 & data_in$Status==input$p2,3]
      selectInput("p3", choices = as.list(plant), label = 'Plant')
    }
  })

  output$selected_data_table<-renderDT({
    if(is.null(values$upload_state)|| values$upload_state=='reset')
    {
      returnValue()
    }
    else
    {
      data_upload_fun()
      data_to_show<-data_in[data_in$WorklistNo==input$p1 & data_in$Status==input$p2 & data_in$Plant== input$p3, ]
      DT::datatable(data_to_show)
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: @Subhasish1315 please comment...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56863566/how-to-do-autofill-of-data-in-shiny-app-using-excel-file/56869292?noredirect=1#comment100397236_56869292) it seems you want to do this reactively. You need to understand the concept of Shiny Reactive component Behavior.

However, Few points need to highlight.

- Make 'data_in<-read_xlsx()' as 'data_in<<-read_xlsx()' to make it global assignment.
- In output$pi_ui you have used 'uploade_data$WorklistNo' which will be 'data_in$WorklistNo'
- I think you are uploading a static excel file. So you need to modify the code according your excel. My code was running on based on my excel. So to make it working you need to change accordingly.

  However you need to give a minimal reproducible code  even you want to work with your data then kindly provide minimal data set.

Revised Code with same dataset(.xlsx file)

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(xlsx)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      fileInput("file_upload","Uplaod Data",buttonLabel = "Browse..",placeholder = "No file Selected")
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(3,
             uiOutput("p1_ui")
      ),
      column(3,
             uiOutput("p2_ui")
      ),
      column(3,
             uiOutput("p3_ui")
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(6,
             h3("Uploaded DATA"),
             DTOutput("uploaded_data_table")
      ),
      column(6,
             h3("Selected DATA"),
             DTOutput("selected_data_table")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  values <- reactiveValues(
    upload_state = NULL
  )
  data_upload_fun<-eventReactive(input$file_upload,{
    req(input$file_upload)
    if(values$upload_state=='reset'||is.null(values$upload_state))
    {
      data_in<<-read.xlsx(input$file_upload$datapath,1)
      values$upload_state <- 'uploaded'
      data_in
    }  
  })


  output$uploaded_data_table <- renderDT({
    DT::datatable(data_upload_fun())
  })
  output$p1_ui<-renderUI({
    if(is.null(values$upload_state)|| values$upload_state=='reset')
    {
      selectInput("p1", choices = NULL, label = 'WorklistNo')
    } 
    else
    {
      data_upload_fun()
      selectInput("p1", choices = data_in$WLID, label = 'WorklistNo')
    }
  })

  output$p2_ui<-renderUI({
    if(is.null(values$upload_state)|| values$upload_state=='reset')
    {
      selectInput("p2", choices = NULL, label = 'Status')
    }
    else
    {
      data_upload_fun()
      status<-data_in[data_in$WLID==input$p1,3]
      selectInput("p2", choices = as.list(status), label = 'Status')
    }
  })
  output$p3_ui<-renderUI({
    if(is.null(values$upload_state)|| values$upload_state=='reset')
    {
      selectInput("p3", choices = NULL, label = 'Plant')
    }
    else
    {
      data_upload_fun()
      plant<-data_in[data_in$WLID==input$p1 & data_in$STATUS==input$p2,2]
      selectInput("p3", choices = as.list(plant), label = 'Plant')
    }
  })

  output$selected_data_table<-renderDT({
    if(is.null(values$upload_state)|| values$upload_state=='reset')
    {
      returnValue()
    }
    else
    {
      data_upload_fun()
      data_to_show<-data_in[data_in$WLID==input$p1 & data_in$STATUS==input$p2 & data_in$PLANT== input$p3, ]
      DT::datatable(data_to_show)
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image][image]

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for your code and help. I have a small question, suppose if my data set is not complete mean few column don't have data but other column in same row have data, will this code be able to run. I tried but its not working if any of the column don't have values it will give NA for other values in same row.   Any suggestion..!

Answer (score 0):

When you call a reactive, you can't reference something that's been created within it - you reference the reactive. So where you reference `data_in`, you should be using `data_upload_fun()`.

The other issue is that `uploade_data` doesn't seem to be a dataset in your code so you have possibly made a typo there or have accidentally not included a dataset.

I can't run your code so I'm not totally sure if that will fix everything but it deals with some of the issues.